# Find the domain of convergence for the series as well as the sum $S(x)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The given series: $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\cos (\pi n) \sin \left(\pi x \right)}{(n+1)n \cot^n x}$$

Here is what I did:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{\cos (\pi n) \sin \left(\pi x \right)}{(n+1)n \cot^n x} \le \frac{1}{n(n+1) \cot^n x} = \left[ y = \cot^n x \right]$$
According to the necessary condition for the series: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)y} = 0 \Rightarrow y \neq 0$$ Then $\cot^n x \neq 0 \Rightarrow x \neq \frac{\pi k}{2} \ \ \forall k \in Z \Rightarrow x \in ] \pi k + \frac{\pi}{2}; \frac{3\pi k}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}[$, where $k \in Z$

I was thinking that I have found the domain of convergence, but I was wrong. I guesss the interval at which the convergence is possible, but it is not domain of the convergence? Also, how do I find the sum $S(x)$ for these series?
$$\sin(\pi x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)}\tan^n(x)$$
$\tan x = y$. Applying ratio test:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left|\frac{n(n+1)y^{n+1}}{y^n(n+1)(n+2)}\right| = \lim_{n\to \infty}\left|\frac{ny}{n+1}\right| = |y|$$
Then $|\tan x|< 1 \iff x\in ]-\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k; \frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k [, \ \ k \in Z$

Comment: Your $y$ depends on $n$. It is clearly a mistake. To find the sum, notice $\cos\pi n=(-1)^n$.

Comment: @metamorphy Ok, then can I write $y = cot x$ and then do the same to find the interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Taylor series for $\log(1+z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}z^n}{n}$, we have for $|z|=|\tan(x)|<1$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(\pi n)\sin(\pi x)}{n(n+1)\cot^n(x)}&=\sin(\pi x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n(n+1)}\tan^n(x)\\\\
&=\sin(\pi x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{(-1)^n\tan^n(x)}{n}-\frac{(-1)^n\tan^n(x)}{n+1}\right)\\\\
&=\sin(\pi x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\tan^n(x)}{n}\\\\&+\sin(\pi x)\cot( x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}\tan^{n+1}(x)}{n+1}\\\\
&=\sin(\pi x)-\sin(\pi x)(1+\cot(x))\log(1+\tan(x))
\end{align}$$

---

The series also converges for $|\tan(x)|=1$. That evaluation is left as a simple exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have a few questions. About the third line, where did that $\cos$ come from? About the fourth line, you bring $sin(\pi x ) + \cos(\pi x)$ out of expression, but the multipliers for them are not equal? Why do you write the sum of tangents as $\sin (\pi x)$? I don't comprehend the last line completely.

Comment: Why is it that "$\sin(\pi x)\tan^n(x)=\cos(\pi x)\tan^{n+1}(x)$ I am a bit confused about indices, I get that you took the first term as if series would have been written as $\cos(x)\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, then the term to subtract would be $-sin(x)$ and you have written $\sin(\pi x)$. Wouldn't the first term for $\cos(x)\sum^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\tan^{n+1}(x)}{n+1}$ be sin(x)?

Comment: Also, why at the beginning you state that $|\tan (x)|< 1$? So, the domain of convergence is $x\in ]-\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}[$, but why?

Comment: I've edited some typographical errors.  As for why we begin with $|\tan(x)|<1$, note that we have power series with the variable $y$ where $y=\tan(x)$.  And as we know, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-y)^n}{n(n+1)}$ fails to converge when $|y|>1$ (the ratio test establishes this quite nicely).  The case for $|y|=1$ is left for the reader.

Comment: Ok, then for $|tanx| = 1$ the series converge because it's alternating series then? Also, is it possible to tell the domain of convergence by the sum or should ratio test be used?

Comment: The ratio test works well here

Comment: Here, I found the convergence domain, I wanted to know if it's correct.

Comment: Yes, the convergence is on $(-\pi/4+k\pi,\pi/4+k\pi)$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.